# Visual C++ Command Line Compiler (CL.EXE) Redirect OBJ Files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-construction, command-line, winapi

The compiler (CL.EXE) can take multiple source files, but likes to generate all the OBJ files in the directory that it is invoked. I couldn't find the compiler flag to set an output directory but I did find one for an individual OBJ, but it can't take multiple sources.

Without having to specify each file to redirect the output and having lots of targets for NMAKE, is there an easy way to do it through CL?

Comment: The /Fo option was made to do this.  Use the IDE's C/C++, Command Line page to see what it does.

Comment: I thought I already tried that. The MSDN made it look like it could only be used on one source file. Could you provide an example?

Comment: You don't really need me to post a screenshot of the Command Line settings page for a project do you?  Surely you can create you own IDE project?

Comment: I don't have the IDE installed, only the Windows SDK. Can't you copy and paste the command line the IDE generates?

Comment: Use the Express edition, it is free.

Comment: Copied and pasted from the Command Line page. Still gave an error about multiple sources. I think it's time for NMAKE.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4126/discussion-between-sevado-and-hans-passant)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It turns out the `/Fo` option actually works, but the directory you specify *must* end with a backslash.  Thus

```
cl  /Fo.\obj\  -c foo.c fee.c
```

Works but `cl /Fo.\obj -c ...` would fail.

Comment: I've been finding it actually has to end with *two* backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the only answer. In case when the obj path is quoted, the trailing backslash has to be either added after the path closing quote, or escaped if added before the quote.

```
cl  /Fo"quoted path\obj"\  -c foo.c fee.c
```

OR

```
cl  "/Foquoted path\obj"\  -c foo.c fee.c
```

OR

```
cl  /Fo"quoted path\obj\\"  -c foo.c fee.c
```

Speaking of `NMAKE`, similar syntax is expected when passing quoted macro values on `NMAKE`
command line. The trailing backslash seems to be the crucial bit to watch for.

```
nmake SOMEDIR="quoted path\obj"\
```

OR

```
nmake SOMEDIR="quoted path\obj\\"
```

OR

```
nmake "SOMEDIR=quoted path\obj"
```

NOT

```
nmake SOMEDIR="quoted path\obj\"
```

as this would result in an escaped quote `\"` and would grab whatever else followed on the command line and put it into `$(SOMEDIR)`. Took me a while to diagnose such a behavior, hope this would save time to someone else.

Comment: Quoting the path seems to change it to an absolute path, so it seems necessary to add `.\` to the front for a relative path. Also, it seems like `cl` doesn't want to create the directory structure itself for some reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56805311/cl-exe-problems-specifing-obj-location-with-fo