# Makefile under Windows Troubles

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I got a Makefile that works just fine under linux. Though, I have tried in two ways to use it under windows:

1) with nmake. I get the error "makefile(122) : fatal error U1033: syntax error : '$(CPPCOMPILER)' unexpected" thats te line "$(CPPCOMPILER) src/train.cpp $(TRANSITION_O) \".

2) with Cygwin and the make plugin: "I get no rule to make target include/aux.cpp required by include/aux.o"

But I can find no proper help online for making a very simple Makefile uch as this one just work under Windows that worked under Linux

```
########################################################################
# variables
########################################################################

LIST_H = include/lists/list.h
LIST_CPP = include/lists/list.cpp
LIST_O = include/lists/list.o

TRANSITION_H = include/lists/transition.h
TRANSITION_CPP = include/lists/transition.cpp
TRANSITION_O = include/lists/transition.o

TRANSITION_LIST_H = include/lists/transitionList.h
TRANSITION_LIST_CPP = include/lists/transitionList.cpp
TRANSITION_LIST_O = include/lists/transitionList.o

STRING_LIST_H = include/lists/stringList.h
STRING_LIST_CPP = include/lists/stringList.cpp
STRING_LIST_O = include/lists/stringList.o

ELEMENT_H = include/lists/element.h
ELEMENT_CPP = include/lists/element.cpp
ELEMENT_O = include/lists/element.o

TEST_CPP = include/lists/test.cpp
TEST_BIN = test.exe

AUX_H = include/aux.h
AUX_CPP = include/aux.cpp
AUX_O = include/aux.o

TRIE_H = include/trie/trie.h
TRIE_CPP = include/trie/trie.cpp
TRIE_O = include/trie/trie.o

HMM_H = include/hmm/hmm.h
HMM_O = include/hmm/hmm.o

TRELLIS_H = include/hmm/trellis.h
TRELLIS_O = include/hmm/trellis.o

TRAINER_H = include/trainer/trainer.h
TRAINER_O = include/trainer/trainer.o

STATICSTICS = data/hmm/x.txt

CPPCOMPILER = cl
CPPCOMPILEROPTIONS1 = /Ox

# doxygen-file
DOC_INDEX = doc/html/index.html

# corpus file
corpus = '../data/tiger.txt'
# comment tag
tag = \#
in = 'data/testfile.txt'

STATS = data/HMM/all_trans.dat


########################################################################
# targets
########################################################################


$(TRANSITION_O) : $(TRANSITION_CPP) $(TRANSITION_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(CPPCOMPILEROPTIONS1) $(TRANSITION_CPP) -o \
    $(TRANSITION_O)

$(TRANSITION_LIST_O) : $(TRANSITION_LIST_CPP) $(TRANSITION_LIST_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(CPPCOMPILEROPTIONS1) $(TRANSITION_LIST_CPP) -o \
    $(TRANSITION_LIST_O)

$(STRING_LIST_O) : $(STRING_LIST_CPP) $(STRING_LIST_H) $(LIST_O) \
    $(ELEMENT_O)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(CPPCOMPILEROPTIONS1) $(STRING_LIST_CPP) -o \
    $(STRING_LIST_O)

$(AUX_O) : $(AUX_CPP) $(AUX_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(CPPCOMPILEROPTIONS1) $(AUX_CPP) -o $(AUX_O)

$(ELEMENT_O) : $(ELEMENT_CPP) $(ELEMENT_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(CPPCOMPILEROPTIONS1) $(ELEMENT_CPP) -o $(ELEMENT_O)

$(LIST_O) : $(LIST_CPP) $(LIST_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(CPPCOMPILEROPTIONS1) $(LIST_CPP) -o $(LIST_O)

$(TRIE_O) : $(TRIE_CPP) $(TRIE_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(CPPCOMPILEROPTIONS1) $(TRIE_CPP) -o $(TRIE_O)

$(HMM_O) : $(HMM_H) $(TRELLIS_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(CPPCOMPILEROPTIONS1) $(HMM_H) -o $(HMM_O)

# make documentation
documentation: $(DOC_INDEX)

$(DOC_INDEX):
    doxygen doc/hmm.doxygen
    mv html doc

clean:
    rm -rf doc/html
    rm -rf doc/latex
    find . -name '*.o' -delete
    find . -name '*.exe' -delete
    find . -name '*.gch' -delete
    find . -name '*.out' -delete
    find . -name '*.png' -delete
    find . -name '*.dat' -delete

# gathers statistics from corpus file to train HMM on. Requires
# one token-tag-tuple per line. call format:
# 'make statistics corpus=<corpus file> tag=<comment tag char>'
statistics: $(STATS)

$(STATS): $(TRANSITION_O) $(TRANSITION_LIST_O) $(AUX_O) $(LIST_O) \
    $(ELEMENT_O) $(TRIE_O) $(STRING_LIST_O)

    $(CPPCOMPILER) src/train.cpp $(TRANSITION_O) \
    $(TRANSITION_LIST_O) $(AUX_O) $(LIST_O) $(ELEMENT_O) $(TRIE_O) \
    $(STRING_LIST_O) -o train.exe
    mv train.exe bin/train.exe
    cd bin; ./train.exe $(corpus) '$(tag)'

# taggs sentences in input file. Requires a sentence to occupy a line
# all by itself; call format: 'make test in=<file>'
test: $(TRANSITION_O) $(TRANSITION_LIST_O) $(AUX_O) $(LIST_O) \
    $(ELEMENT_O) $(TRIE_O) $(STRING_LIST_O) $(STATS) $(HMM_O)

    $(CPPCOMPILER) src/hmm_test.cpp $(TRANSITION_O) \
    $(TRANSITION_LIST_O) $(AUX_O) $(LIST_O) $(ELEMENT_O) $(TRIE_O) \
    $(STRING_LIST_O) -o hmm_test.exe
    mv hmm_test.exe bin/hmm_test.exe
    cd bin; ./hmm_test.exe ../$(in)
```

## EDIT

I got make to work under windows now, but it still behaves weird, producing object files in the same directory the Makefile is located, rather than in their own respective directories.

```
########################################################################
# variables
########################################################################

LIST_H = include\lists\list.h
LIST_CPP = include\lists\list.cpp
LIST_O = include\lists\list.obj

TRANSITION_H = include\lists\transition.h
TRANSITION_CPP = include\lists\transition.cpp
TRANSITION_O = include\lists\transition.obj

TRANSITION_LIST_H = include\lists\transitionList.h
TRANSITION_LIST_CPP = include\lists\transitionList.cpp
TRANSITION_LIST_O = include\lists\transitionList.obj

STRING_LIST_H = include\lists\stringList.h
STRING_LIST_CPP = include\lists\stringList.cpp
STRING_LIST_O = include\lists\stringList.obj

ELEMENT_H = include\lists\element.h
ELEMENT_CPP = include\lists\element.cpp
ELEMENT_O = include\lists\element.obj

TEST_CPP = include\lists\test.cpp
TEST_BIN = test.exe

AUXILS_H = include\auxils.h
AUXILS_CPP = include\auxils.cpp
AUXILS_O = include\auxils.obj

TRIE_H = include\trie\trie.h
TRIE_CPP = include\trie\trie.cpp
TRIE_O = include\trie\trie.obj

HMM_H = include\hmm\hmm.h
HMM_O = include\hmm\hmm.obj

TRELLIS_H = include\hmm\trellis.h
TRELLIS_O = include\hmm\trellis.obj

TRAINER_H = include\trainer\trainer.h
TRAINER_O = include\trainer\trainer.obj

CPPCOMPILER = cl

# doxygen-file
DOC_INDEX = doc\html\index.html

# corpus file
corpus = '..\data\tiger.txt'
# comment tag
tag = \#
in = 'data\testfile.txt'

STATS = data\HMM\all_trans.dat


########################################################################
# targets
########################################################################


$(TRANSITION_O) : $(TRANSITION_CPP) $(TRANSITION_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(TRANSITION_CPP)

$(TRANSITION_LIST_O) : $(TRANSITION_LIST_CPP) $(TRANSITION_LIST_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(TRANSITION_LIST_CPP)

$(STRING_LIST_O) : $(STRING_LIST_CPP) $(STRING_LIST_H) $(LIST_O) \
    $(ELEMENT_O)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(STRING_LIST_CPP) 

$(AUXILS_O) : $(AUXILS_CPP) $(AUXILS_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(AUXILS_CPP)

$(ELEMENT_O) : $(ELEMENT_CPP) $(ELEMENT_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(ELEMENT_CPP)

$(LIST_O) : $(LIST_CPP) $(LIST_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(LIST_CPP)

$(TRIE_O) : $(TRIE_CPP) $(TRIE_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(TRIE_CPP)

$(HMM_O) : $(HMM_H) $(TRELLIS_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(HMM_H)

# make documentation
documentation: $(DOC_INDEX)

$(DOC_INDEX):
    doxygen doc\hmm.doxygen
    mv html doc

clean:
    rm -rf doc\html
    rm -rf doc\latex
    find . -name '*.obj' -delete
    find . -name '*.exe' -delete
    find . -name '*.gch' -delete
    find . -name '*.out' -delete
    find . -name '*.png' -delete
    find . -name '*.dat' -delete

# gathers statistics from corpus file to train HMM on. Requires
# one token-tag-tuple per line. call format:
# 'make statistics corpus=<corpus file> tag=<comment tag char>'
statistics: $(STATS)

$(STATS): $(TRANSITION_O) $(TRANSITION_LIST_O) $(AUXILS_O) $(LIST_O) \
    $(ELEMENT_O) $(TRIE_O) $(STRING_LIST_O)

    $(CPPCOMPILER) src\train.cpp $(TRANSITION_O) \
    $(TRANSITION_LIST_O) $(AUXILS_O) $(LIST_O) $(ELEMENT_O) $(TRIE_O) \
    $(STRING_LIST_O)
    mv train.exe bin\train.exe
    cd bin; train.exe $(corpus) '$(tag)'

# taggs sentences in input file. Requires a sentence to occupy a line
# all by itself; call format: 'make test in=<file>'
test: $(TRANSITION_O) $(TRANSITION_LIST_O) $(AUXILS_O) $(LIST_O) \
    $(ELEMENT_O) $(TRIE_O) $(STRING_LIST_O) $(STATS) $(HMM_O)

    $(CPPCOMPILER) src\hmm_test.cpp $(TRANSITION_O) \
    $(TRANSITION_LIST_O) $(AUXILS_O) $(LIST_O) $(ELEMENT_O) $(TRIE_O) \
    $(STRING_LIST_O)
    mv hmm_test.exe bin\hmm_test.exe
    cd bin; hmm_test.exe ..\$(in)
```

## EDIT 2

I added the object file flag according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb8e9b8y.aspx

But apparently I got it wrong. I  get:

```
C:\<path>>make test
cl /Fo\include\lists\transition.obj include\lists\transition.cpp

transition.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(337) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not
enabled. Specify /EHsc
C:\<path>\include\lists\transition.cpp : fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: '\in
clude\lists\transition.obj': No such file or directory
make: *** [\include\lists\transition.obj] Error 1






########################################################################
    # variables
```

#

```
LIST_H = include\lists\list.h
LIST_CPP = include\lists\list.cpp
LIST_O = \include\lists\list.obj

TRANSITION_H = include\lists\transition.h
TRANSITION_CPP = include\lists\transition.cpp
TRANSITION_O = \include\lists\transition.obj

TRANSITION_LIST_H = include\lists\transitionList.h
TRANSITION_LIST_CPP = include\lists\transitionList.cpp
TRANSITION_LIST_O = \include\lists\transitionList.obj

STRING_LIST_H = include\lists\stringList.h
STRING_LIST_CPP = include\lists\stringList.cpp
STRING_LIST_O = \include\lists\stringList.obj

ELEMENT_H = include\lists\element.h
ELEMENT_CPP = include\lists\element.cpp
ELEMENT_O = \include\lists\element.obj

TEST_CPP = include\lists\test.cpp
TEST_BIN = test.exe

AUXILS_H = include\auxils.h
AUXILS_CPP = include\auxils.cpp
AUXILS_O = \include\auxils.obj

TRIE_H = include\trie\trie.h
TRIE_CPP = include\trie\trie.cpp
TRIE_O = \include\trie\trie.obj

HMM_H = include\hmm\hmm.h
HMM_O = \include\hmm\hmm.obj

TRELLIS_H = include\hmm\trellis.h
TRELLIS_O = \include\hmm\trellis.obj

TRAINER_H = include\trainer\trainer.h
TRAINER_O = \include\trainer\trainer.obj

CPPCOMPILER = cl
TO_OBJ = /Fo

# doxygen-file
DOC_INDEX = doc\html\index.html

# corpus file
corpus = '..\data\tiger.txt'
# comment tag
tag = \#
in = 'data\testfile.txt'

STATS = data\HMM\all_trans.dat


########################################################################
# targets
########################################################################


$(TRANSITION_O) : $(TRANSITION_CPP) $(TRANSITION_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(TO_OBJ)$(TRANSITION_O) $(TRANSITION_CPP)

$(TRANSITION_LIST_O) : $(TRANSITION_LIST_CPP) $(TRANSITION_LIST_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(TO_OBJ)$(TRANSITION_LIST_O) $(TRANSITION_LIST_CPP)

$(STRING_LIST_O) : $(STRING_LIST_CPP) $(STRING_LIST_H) $(LIST_O) \
    $(ELEMENT_O)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(TO_OBJ)$(STRING_LIST_O) $(STRING_LIST_CPP)

$(AUXILS_O) : $(AUXILS_CPP) $(AUXILS_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(TO_OBJ)$(AUXILS_O) $(AUXILS_CPP)

$(ELEMENT_O) : $(ELEMENT_CPP) $(ELEMENT_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(TO_OBJ)$(ELEMENT_O) $(ELEMENT_CPP)

$(LIST_O) : $(LIST_CPP) $(LIST_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(TO_OBJ)$(LIST_O) $(LIST_CPP)

$(TRIE_O) : $(TRIE_CPP) $(TRIE_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(TO_OBJ)$(TRIE_O) $(TRIE_CPP)

$(HMM_O) : $(HMM_H) $(TRELLIS_H)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(TO_OBJ)$(HMM_O) $(HMM_H)

# make documentation
documentation: $(DOC_INDEX)

$(DOC_INDEX):
    doxygen doc\hmm.doxygen
    mv html doc

clean:
    rm -rf doc\html
    rm -rf doc\latex
    find . -name '*.obj' -delete
    find . -name '*.exe' -delete
    find . -name '*.gch' -delete
    find . -name '*.out' -delete
    find . -name '*.png' -delete
    find . -name '*.dat' -delete

# gathers statistics from corpus file to train HMM on. Requires
# one token-tag-tuple per line. call format:
# 'make statistics corpus=<corpus file> tag=<comment tag char>'
statistics: $(STATS)

$(STATS): $(TRANSITION_O) $(TRANSITION_LIST_O) $(AUXILS_O) $(LIST_O) \
    $(ELEMENT_O) $(TRIE_O) $(STRING_LIST_O)

    $(CPPCOMPILER) src\train.cpp $(TRANSITION_O) \
    $(TRANSITION_LIST_O) $(AUXILS_O) $(LIST_O) $(ELEMENT_O) $(TRIE_O) \
    $(STRING_LIST_O)
    mv train.exe bin\train.exe
    cd bin; train.exe $(corpus) '$(tag)'

# taggs sentences in input file. Requires a sentence to occupy a line
# all by itself; call format: 'make test in=<file>'
test: $(TRANSITION_O) $(TRANSITION_LIST_O) $(AUXILS_O) $(LIST_O) \
    $(ELEMENT_O) $(TRIE_O) $(STRING_LIST_O) $(STATS) $(HMM_O)

    $(CPPCOMPILER) src\hmm_test.cpp $(TRANSITION_O) \
    $(TRANSITION_LIST_O) $(AUXILS_O) $(LIST_O) $(ELEMENT_O) $(TRIE_O) \
    $(STRING_LIST_O)
    mv hmm_test.exe bin\hmm_test.exe
    cd bin; hmm_test.exe ..\$(in)
```

ANd when I remove the blackslash before include (which would not agree with the template on the MS website) I get:

```
/out:transitionList.exe
include\lists\transitionList.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
make: *** [include\lists\transitionList.obj] Error 2
```

Comment: Is that file available at that path from your current directory? What does `ls include/aux.cpp` say in your current directory (the same directory you run `make` from)? (Also this makefile is very over specified and can be **significantly** trimmed down.)

Comment: lol, it isn't there. I put the whole project in my dropbox to get it onto my windows machine... but apparently "aux" is a reserved file name under windows, causing it not having got synced... That really is the LAST THING EVER that would have occurred to me...

Comment: Well, after fixing this, and remain the file and its pathes everywhere I still get the same error for nmake. With cygwin I couldn't test yet, as I don't know how to compile with it yet.

Comment: Yes, nmake and gnu make are not compatible. You cannot use nmake here. Just run make in the same directory as the makefile. The same as you did when you got that error in the first place. That should do what you need. (Or `make target` whatever command you ran on not-Windows).

Comment: okay, thanks. just not getting anything make related to work under windows. But that's out of scope...

Comment: Whatever you ran in the first place that got you the error about `include/aux.cpp`. Run that again now. What happens?

Comment: Okay, I got make to work under windows now, using this tool https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow My Makefile looks like in the edit now. I am getting a linker error about an entry point that must be defined, and it produces object files in the same directory the makefiel is located

Comment: Your edited makefile doesn't use the `-o` flag on your compilation rules so it doesn't put the files where you want them to go. **What** linker error? You need to be specific.

Comment: Right, thanks. I added an edit

Comment: And have you tried putting that error into a search engine?

Comment: Yes, and those are not helpful. I know my code compiles. It does under Linux.  So it must have to do with make syntax or path formats under windows.

Comment: Btw. I am compiling source files with functions from classes, so there obviouyl is no main() in those.

Comment: That's not a make issue. That's a "you don't have an entry point" issue. Where is your entry point and what is it called? What is `transitionList.exe`? It isn't in your makefiles anywhere.

Comment: Not having an entry point is the problem. You are trying to link such that one is expected. Are you trying to create a binary or an object file?

Comment: object file (4 more words to go)

Comment: If you are trying to create an object file then it would seem your compilation command is simply incorrect. But seeing as how that error cannot possibly be coming from the shown makefiles and the fact that I know nothing about `cl` I can't really help any more at this point.

Comment: Well, thanks so much anyway :) But I am kind of getting there. i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706490/visual-c-command-line-compiler-cl-exe-redirect-obj-files and now I am a step further. I added '.' and '\' ad the front or end espetively of all Object file path. But apparently '\' at the end of a path is not being recognized, and escaping it with \\ doesn't help either. SO pathes for object files now look like ELEMENT_O = .\include\lists\element.obj\\